# Random Href using jquery and colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

FYI, I am not at all a programmer so anything will have to spelled out clearly.

I am using this .js script inside sharepoint.  It works fine!

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>ColorBox demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, there!</h1>
    <h2>This is some content</h2>
    <p>The popup will open in five seconds</p>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
      function openColorBox(){
        $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"40%", height:"30%", href: "http://172.16.96.254/pf17.html"});
      }

      setTimeout(openColorBox, 5000);
      setTimeout(parent.$.colorbox.close, 15000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

I have created several Pages on a local internal site.  pf1.html - pf21.html

I would like to randomize these when the popup runs.

I have seen this function..posted in this forum.

(Math.random()*11)

How can I add this to the above script and randomize the pages.

This is the full random clip

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.colorbox").click(function() {
$(this).attr("href","print"+Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+".html");
});
```

I know the *11 sets the number of pages..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
  function openColorBox(){
     var urlBase = "http://172.16.96.254/pf";
     var urlPage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
     var urlExt = ".html";

     var randomizedURL = urlBase + urlPage + urlExt;

     $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"40%", height:"30%", href: randomizedURL});
  }

  setTimeout(openColorBox, 5000);
  setTimeout(parent.$.colorbox.close, 15000);
```